# How do I set up a self-timer in Xamarin.Forms using Plugin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am building a program in Xamarin.Forms that uses a camera with Plugin.Media.CrossMedia.
I want to start it with a self-timer set to 10 seconds.
The options in the constructor when starting appear to be limited to

```
Directory
DefaultCamera
Name
Photosize
SaveToAlbum
CustomPhotoSize
AllowCropping
CumpressionQuality
Location
MaxWidthHeight
ModalPrensentationStyle
OverlayViewProvider
RotateImage
SaveMetaData
```

How do I set up a self-timer in Xamarin.Forms using Plugin.

```
using PhotoImage.Model;
using Plugin.Media.Abstractions;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

public class CameraBaseViewPage : ContentPage
{
    public async Task CaptureCamera(StoreCameraMediaOptions config)
    {
        await Plugin.Media.CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

        if (!Plugin.Media.CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !Plugin.Media.CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
        {
            return;
        }

        var file = await Plugin.Media.CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(
        config ??
        new StoreCameraMediaOptions
        {
            Directory = "Photo",
            DefaultCamera = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.CameraDevice.Front,
            Name = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MMdd_HHmm") + "Photo" + ".jpg",
            PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Custom,
            SaveToAlbum = true,
            CustomPhotoSize = 20,
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't believe the plugin supports taking a photo without user interaction.  You would need to use the platform camera APIs to do this.

Comment: One way to do this is to use the [LEADTOOLS Xamarin Camera Control](https://leadtools.com/sdk/xamarin/camera). (Disclosure: I work for its vendors). Its CameraView Class gives you control using the ICamera Interface, which has a [TakePicture Method](https://leadtools.com/help/sdk/v22/dh/xamarin/cx/icamera-takepicture.html) that you can call from your code. There’s a free evaluation [here](https://leadtools.com/downloads) and an introductory Camera Control tutorial [here](https://leadtools.com/help/sdk/v22/tutorials/xamarin-integrate-live-capture-with-xamarin-camera-control.html)